# why can't I set \columncolor via \setkeys?

Tags: xkeyval

I'm trying to create a new columntype with options as in the source below, and all option work fine, except for the `b` option, which gives this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\KV@xcol@b #1->\columncolor 
                            {#1}
```

When I use the `\columncolor}` directly, as in the second `tabularx` below, ther is no problem. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={90mm,60mm},margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,xkeyval,xcolor,colortbl,tabularx,ragged2e}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent0pt

% keys for columntype x:
\makeatletter
\define@key{xcol}{w}{\hsize=#1\hsize}       % relative width (summarize to 1)
\define@key{xcol}{f}{\leavevmode\color{#1}} % foreground color
\define@key{xcol}{b}{\columncolor{#1}}      % background color
\define@key{xcol}{r}[]{\RaggedLeft}         % justify right
\define@key{xcol}{l}[]{\RaggedRight}        % justify left (the default)
\define@key{xcol}{c}[]{\Centering}          % center
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\setkeys{xcol}{#1}}X}

\begin{document}

% the b=yellow should make \colorcolumn{yellow}, but \columncolor is undefined?
\begin{tabularx}{80mm}[t]{|x{f=blue,b=yellow,w=.7,c}|x{w=.3,r}|}\hline
Hello & World\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip

% using \columncolor directly: no problem:
\begin{tabularx}{50mm}[t]{|>{\columncolor{yellow}}x{f=blue,w=.7,r}|x{w=.3}|}\hline
Hello & World\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be similar to having `\multicolumn` as the *first* entry in a cell. Your setting of keys makes `\columncolor` not the *first* thing in the cell.

Comment: You can't use `\columncolor` in a cell. `\columncolor{yellow} Hello` would give the same error. As you hide it in a setkeys-command you are too late. Use `\cellcolor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\columncolor` isn't really a command that is executed so much as a marker for a place that tokens are inserted (in fact it is not defined at all as a command).

Somewhere in `colortbl` you find

```
\expandafter\CT@extract\the\toks\@tempcnta\columncolor!\@nil
```

...

```
\def\CT@extract#1\columncolor#2#3\@nil{%...
```

So `\CT@extract` needs to see an explicit `\columncolor` token, not hidden behind a macro or brace groups.

The reasons for doing it that way are somewhat obscure:-)

Comment: I took a look ... really complicated! So I'll have to prefix my x-columns with >{\columncolor...}